# How to make window fade out slowly when I click the close button by PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-3.5, pyqt5

Here is the code. My idea is when I click the button, the window will became transparent from the bottom to the top slowly, and then the window's transparency is 0 and lastly the window closes, but I don't know how to do this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout,QApplication)

class Window(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):   
    QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    button = QPushButton(self.tr("Click me!"))

    button.clicked.connect(self.fade)

    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(button)

def fade(self):   
    self.setWindowOpacity(0.2)
    QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.unfade)#it does not work
    self.close()

def unfade(self):
    self.setWindowOpacity(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try the following code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/6a582ec1db6e7e89a8da24ceab76a1e7 and tell me what it's missing to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. That is the effect what I want, but how the button connect the close event? I mean when I click the button, the window closes in that way

Comment: Explain better please.

Comment: So, you want it to run when you close the window, that is when you press the button, and when it finishes, it will close?

Comment: Correct. That is what I mean.

Comment: Okay, wait a moment, please.

Comment: Already, try the code and if it works mark it as correct please.

Comment: It worked for you?

Comment: Sometimes it does not fade out slowly and close directly. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Thats weird. Have you identified a pattern or is it random? Are you testing my code or have you modified it?

Comment: I didn't change anything of it. The version of Python is 3.5.0, and the os is windows10.

Comment: Change `self.animation.setEndValue(-1)` to `self.animation.setEndValue(0)`

Comment: Sometimes it give this message: "QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property heightPercentage of your QObject"

Comment: It seems strange to me to say that sometimes, if there is a problem of versions I should always say it. Do you have a teamviewer?

Comment: mmmm something new?

Comment: Well, I don't have a teamviewer. And I think it is enough for me to use. Anyway, thank you very much : )

Comment: Please if my answer helps you mark it as correct please.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know why I cannot vote : (

Comment: It seems like the system blocked my account.

Comment: It's one thing to vote for which you need a minimum reputation, I think 15; instead another thing is to mark an answer as correct for which only you need to press the arrow to the left side of my answer, for more information look at the content of the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I pressed the arrow, but it was useless.

Comment: Have you pressed the green arrow?

Comment: I have another question to ask, but the system had blocked my account. So sad.

Comment: Here is what it told me. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect you want we can create it using the `setMask()` method that only makes the widget part visible to the region, so we must vary the height of the region for that we will use the class `QPropertyAnimation`, but for this we must create a property through `pyqtProperty`. this task will be launched in the `closeEvent()` method as shown below:

```
class FadeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):   
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self._heightMask = self.height()
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"heightPercentage")
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.height())
        self.animation.setEndValue(-1)
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.isStarted = False

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def heightMask(self):
        return self._heightMask

    @heightMask.setter
    def heightPercentage(self, value):
        self._heightMask = value
        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.heightMask)
        self.setMask(QRegion(rect))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.isStarted:
            self.animation.start()
            self.isStarted = True
            event.ignore()
        else:   
            QWidget.closeEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FadeWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi, sometimes it does not fade out slowly and close directly. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fadeout speed can be adjusted by adjusting the `time.sleep()` value of the `fade` function.

It's not as smooth as a real animation, but it'll be useful.

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class FadeWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText("Close")

        button.resize(200, 200)
        button.clicked.connect(self.fade)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.resize(300, 300)

    def fade(self):
        for i in range(10):
            i = i / 10
            self.setWindowOpacity(1 - i)
            time.sleep(0.05)
        self.close()

    def close(self):
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FadeWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```